# Moving webapp from localhost to server - page cannot be found

Tags: java, http, tomcat, networking, playframework-1.x

I have developed a Play! 1.2.7 web application which calls an existing online payment service, eclipsified to work in Java.

I send data in `POST` to a servlet and get a response in `GET` to my application. This is possible because one of the data sent to the service is the URL of my controller handling the response.

I had this working perfectly in local environment but when I move the webapp to a Tomcat container on our local server with public ip I'm stuck because service response cannot find my webapp as it used to do with localhost.

Locally the URL was something like

```
http://localhost:port/myAction
```

When I put it on tomcat I changed the URL to

```
http://my.public.ip.address:tomcat_port/app_name/myAction
```

I get the "page is not available" message from browser.
My guess is that I miss some basics from network communication and I'd like to know how to have this working when the application is deployed on our server.

Ps. sorry for bad tagging, I'm not sure what's this question's target

EDIT: no logs from catalina.out. If I run the application nothing gets logged

Comment: Any error in the logfiles?Why do not use the `app_name` in local environment?

Comment: @Jens In local environment it is not necessary and the routing is defined in an appropriate route config file. On Tomcat default is to specify app name as first thing after address and port and this is due to the fact that you must specify which of the many application you refer to. Nothing useful on the log files, by the way I'm updating the question with the latest messages

Comment: Do you have access to any other applications running on your tomcat server?

Comment: @Andreas we have 3 running applications on our Tomcat server. This is roughly my first experience

Comment: How did you deploy your app.war? And is there a folder called TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/app_name/ ?

Comment: Have you tried to set the application.baseUrl= setting in application.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the solution by knowing that loopback is not enable by default on every router.
So I will never be able to have a response client side when I send the request from the lan where the server is located, unless loopback is enabled on the router.

To test my application I had to use the server local address, visible from inside.